# 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: git, bash, sh

После запуска скрипта через VSCode получаю следующую ошибку, как мне это исправить ?

```
sh -ac 'if test "$TESTS_ENV"; then cp environments/env.${TESTS_ENV}.json.template environments/env.json; fi'

'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webdriverio@1.0.0 config: `sh -ac 'if test "$TESTS_ENV"; then cp environments/env.${TESTS_ENV}.json.template environments/env.json; fi'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webdriverio@1.0.0 config script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vladi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-26T08_22_50_909Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webdriverio@1.0.0 test:chrome:ui: `cross-env TESTS_ENV=ui npm run config && ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config/wdio.chrome.conf.js --spec ./test/specs/books/deleteBookPartsAndChapters.spec.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webdriverio@1.0.0 test:chrome:ui script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

```
"test:chrome:ui": "cross-env TESTS_ENV=ui npm run config && ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config/wdio.chrome.conf.js --spec ./test/specs/books/deleteBookPartsAndChapters.spec.js"
```

Comment: Ну, вообще это для linux команда. Если установлен git for windows, то нужно добавить папку usr/bin в переменную окружения PATH.

Comment: @insolor ну я погуглил и добавил в path вот это C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe, где у меня именно этот sh.exe лежит, но все равно не работает, или это не то что нужно ?

Comment: А просто если из cmd выполнить команду sh тоже ошибку покажет?

Comment: @insolor да, то же самое: 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Значит либо не добавили C:\Program Files\Git\bin\ в path, либо комп нужно перезагрузить

Comment: @insolor поменял path на именно C:\Program Files\Git\bin\, а не C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe и все заработало, но теперь появилась другая идентичная проблема, только вместо sh - точка, не знаете что можно сделать?

Comment: Текст ошибки напишите

Comment: @insolor '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: А вообще что за скрипт запускаете?

Comment: @insolor это автоматизация тестирования, там по факту запуск джс файла с определенным конфигом и параметрами

Comment: Больше язык скрипта интересует, а не для чего он) Если это .sh скрипт, то и запускать его нужно сразу через sh, а у вас похоже запуск идет с помощью cmd.

Comment: @insolor java script

Comment: Добавьте сам скрипт в вопрос

Comment: Добавленный кусок как-то ни о чем мне не говорит. Нужен код, который данную строку запускает. Вообще скорее всего вам придется запускать ваши скрипты или через Linux, или через WSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавить в path путь к папке C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Comment: Спасибо! На случай если кто-то задастся вопросом как добавить - в `PowerShell` надо сделать `$env:Path += ';C:\Program Files\Git'`